# Cannot consume tombstone message for Protobuff message .NET core

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, kafka-consumer-api

I am using .net 7 console app and official confluent kafka package for reading protobuff messages.

My code is

```cs
var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<string, Profile>(consumerConfig)
    .SetValueDeserializer(new ProtobufDeserializer().AsSyncOverAsync())
    .SetErrorHandler((_, e) => Console.WriteLine($"Error: {e.Reason}"))
    .Build();
```

Form this article
https://medium.com/@damienthomlutz/deleting-records-in-kafka-aka-tombstones-651114655a16

I found that

> *How do we delete? A record with the same key from the record we want to delete is produced to the same topic and partition with a null
> payload. These records are called tombstones.
> A null payload is a payload with 0 bytes. A possible mistake here would be to send a “null” string encoded to UTF-8. It will not be
> interpreted as a tombstone. For example, if a customer requests his
> data to be deleted, a tombstone is pushed to the customer topic with
> the key from the customer.*

So, I try to read Tombstone message with Value null for protobuff message.

But I always get error ***Expecting data framing of length 6 bytes or more but total data size is 0 bytes.***

How I see it -  in package there is one check in Confluent.Kafka.Consumer line 916 that package tries to check (and return) if value is null - but it always sets data 0 bytes and returns exception :

> *Unhandled exception. Confluent.Kafka.ConsumeException: Local: Value deserialization error
> ---> System.IO.InvalidDataException: Expecting data framing of length 6 bytes or more but total data size is 0 bytes at
> Confluent.SchemaRegistry.Serdes.ProtobufDeserializer1.DeserializeAsync(ReadOnlyMemory1
> data, Boolean isNull, SerializationContext context) at
> Confluent.Kafka.SyncOverAsync.SyncOverAsyncDeserializer1.Deserialize(ReadOnlySpan1
> data, Boolean isNull, SerializationContext context) at
> Confluent.Kafka.Consumer`2.Consume(Int32 millisecondsTimeout)*

**# Confluent.KafkaConsumer.cs ( line 916)** - This is official package that handle protobuff messages

```cs
try
{
    unsafe
    { 
        val = valueDeserializer.Deserialize(
            msg.val == IntPtr.Zero ? ReadOnlySpan.Empty : new ReadOnlySpan(msg.val.ToPointer(), (int)msg.len),
            msg.val == IntPtr.Zero,
            new SerializationContext(MessageComponentType.Value, topic, headers));
    }
```

Can anyone help or share an idea what I am doing wrong ?